# How to active Switch when dynamic form input changes in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Well, this question came after this question of mine.
[How to disable button if multiple form inputs do not change in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70203200/how-to-disable-button-if-multiple-form-inputs-do-not-change-in-vue-js/)

There is Switch at every form. When a form inputs are changed, the switch needs to be `ON` from the `OFF` state. I have done it by putting this line into the `watch` method on each form

```
this.items.forEach( (_, index) => {
  this.$watch(['items', index].join('.'), {deep: true, handler: (newVal, oldVal) => {
      this.changed.push(newVal.id)
      this.items[index].switch = true
     }});
  });
```

After adding this line, `this.items[index].switch = true`, the `Switch` is getting `ON` from `OFF`; but if a user then `OFF` the `Switch` again by clicking on the `Switch`; the text is not changing anymore. It's always remaining `ON`. how to fix that?

**[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/lr_73/pen/XWebNPy?editors=101)**

Comment: Change `['items', index].join('.')` to `\`items.${index}.items\``

Comment: The `Save` button remains disabled then

Answer (score 0):

If you add this line to watch every time you change this model the switch is set to true. You need a conditional, try this.

```js
this.items[index].switch = this.changed.includes(newOld.id)
```